# UITabBar iOS 11 extra place

Tags: ios, iphone, tabbar, ios11, xcode9

There are extra place in uitabbar in iOS 11.
That's how tabbar looks on iOS 10:
[image]

And that's how tabbar looks on iOS 11:
[image]

Anybody know what can be wrong and how to fix it?

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I used `[UITabBarController setViewControllers: ];` method like this:

```
  [self setViewControllers:@[self.viewControllers[0], self.viewControllers[1], pnc, navigationConroller]];
```

before each call of tabbar's class.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.  I was adding a ChildViewController to the UITabBarController.  The additional tabBarItem did not appear in iOS 10, but appeared in iOS 11, similar to your example.
Hope this helps.

Comment: And this happened in my case too. Thanks!